# WiFi issues when using Magic Mouse

Tags: wifi, mouse, router

I am having issues with WiFi connection since I started using Magic Mouse.
I'm using a 15" MacBook Retina mid 2012 with El Capitan.
The connection is much slower on the MacBook than any other devices when I run speed tests.
Ping is around 300ms instead of 10ms which I am getting on other devices. Also speed is lower on the MacBook.
Sometimes things are so bad that I cannot establish a connection to remote hosts and things go in timeout (e.g. http, Skype, and other protocols and ports).

I've read elsewhere that it's recommended to change the frequency which the router operates from 2.4 GHz to 5 GHz. However this is not an option for me as I don't control the network infrastructure of the places where I use the MacBook.

Are there any other fixes for this issue? If not, do you think I can ask Apple for a refund as they clearly are incompetent dealing with this?

**Update:**

See result of pinging google.com, from the screenshot it's possible to see how initially the ping time seems normal but then it went up or even goes in timeout from the exact moment when I switched on the Magic Mouse
[image: screenshot of ping response]

Answer (score 1):

install 10.11.2 update and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately still experiencing the issue with 10.11.2

Comment: Just added a screenshot of the ping response I get when the Magic Mouse is switched on